# join command in linux says that files aren't sorted but they are

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, join

I have 2 files, I want to join them. they are both sorted.
I sorted them by these commands:

```
$sort -n -k1,1 f1 > t1
$echo $?
0
$mv t1  f1
$sort -n -k1,1 f2 > t1
$echo $?
0
$mv t1 f2
```

now I run the join command

```
$join -1 1 -2 1 f1 f2 > fjoin
$echo $?
1
```

It says those files aren't sorted

```
$cat f1
0 0
5 0
9 0
10 0 <----- problem is here
$cat f2
0 1
3 1
11 2 <----- problem is here
```

Comment: Join requires *lexical* sorting, not *numeric*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to remove sort's option `-n`.

From `man join`:

> Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields. E.g., use `sort -k 1b,1` if `join` has no options, or use `join -t ''` if `sort` has no options. Note, comparisons honor the rules specified by `LC_COLLATE`. If the input is not sorted and some lines cannot be joined, a warning message will be given.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced sort -k 1,1 with sort -k 1b,1. and I removed -n from sort then it worked